# Make wireguard listen on multiple port

Tags: iptables, port, wireguard

It there a way to make wireguar listen to multiple port ? 
Like listenning on 80,53,and 4444.

I'm looking to achieve this without running multiple wire guard separate interface, to prevent having to create different subnet for the same thing.

The reason behind this is to ensure maximum reachability of my server when on public network, who sometimes have diferrent port oppened.

If not included in the software, I was thinking of doing something with iptable but i'm not sure how to "redirect" this port.

I have looked in the wireguard documentation but to no avail.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick

```
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -i eth0 -d <yourIP/32> -p udp -m multiport --dports 53,80,4444  -j REDIRECT --to-ports 15351
```

Comment: Trying to implement this; Im confused to which ip is `<yourIP/32>` ? is it the wg server ip, the client wg ip ? asking because the client wg ip is `/24` for me

Answer (score 0):

Here's the rule one may use in `FireHOL` firewall configuration with WireGuard listening on default 51820

```
redirect4 to 51820 inface eth0 proto udp dport 53
```